# Retrieve newly updated article without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'd like to make a edit link to update the article when it's clicked,
In the template, it's structured as:

- post-text

  - article-content
  - article-form
- post-menu

I hide "article-form" in first place as `<div class="article-form" style="display: none;">` until edit link is clicked.

```
<div class = "col-md-12 post-text" >
    <div class="article-content">
        {{article.content}}
    </div>

    <div class="article-form" style="display: none;">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="/article/edit/{{ b.id }}" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="editContent" name="content" rows="10" cols="30"> 
                    {{form.content.value}} 
                </textarea >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" >
            <div class="col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-12">
                <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-success btn-sm" id = "saveEditBtn"> Save Edits </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form> 
    </div><!-- article-form -->
</div>

<div class="post-menu pull-left">
    <a id="editArticleLink" href="{% url 'article:article_edit' article.id  %}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true">edit </span>
    </a>
    <a id="delArticleLink">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true">delete</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

After updating is completed and submit is cliked, send data to backend using Ajax, hide "article-form" and show "article-content".

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
$(".post-menu a").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //retrieve the topmost element which the target lives in 
    $postText = $(e.target).closest(".post-text");
    //hide article-content
    $postText.find(".article-content").hide();
    //show the article-form for users to update 
    $postText.find(".article-form").show();

    //capture the button submitting event
    $(".article-form button").on("click", function(e){
        var content = $postText.find("textarea").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: ,
            data:,
            success: function(){
                //if saved successfully
                $postText.find(".article-content").show();
                $postText.find(".article-form").hide();
            },//success
        })//ajax post request
    });//nested button click event
}) //click event
)//ready
</script>
```

My problem is that in `ajax success`, 
`$postText.find(".article-content").show()` still display the non-updated article,

How could I retrieve the updated without refreshing the page?

Comment: You mean after send ajax request, want to update article from edited form?

Comment: Yes after sending Ajax request, `$postText.find(".article-content").show();` to show the edited data @seuling

Comment: For simply, it's impossible. Because django render context when sending response, but your page is not loaded after ajax request. For doing this, you may have to send other rendered response from ajax request and add that in your html directly

Comment: Also, you have option to use frontend framework like vue or react. If using them, you can simply bind data after ajax for your articles

Comment: I don't get it... If you can send the edited version to server... You have the new content! Update the `.article-content` with it then show.

Comment: oh, I got it,change textarea.val(), thank you. @LouysPatriceBessette could you please transmit your comment unchanged to answer.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette It's simple answer, but it's trick - not change all data from updated one. If the form data have many one, you can't updated all value from changed form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can send the edited version to server... You have the new content! Update the `.article-content` with it then show.

Here is what I think it is...

```
//capture the button submitting event
$(".article-form button").on("click", function(e){
  var content = $postText.find("textarea").val();
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: ,
    data:,  // <-- There is something missing here... I assume it's content.
    success: function(){
      //if saved successfully
      $postText.find(".article-content").html(content).show();  // update before the show!
      $postText.find(".article-form").hide();
    },//success
  })//ajax post request
});
```